# Command Line Argument. Calc, multiplication(*) not working

Tags: c

I'm new to C and is learning how to pass in command line arguments.
My Calc program is suppose to except 3 arguments.
./calc 4 + 3
should out put 7.
Addition, Division, Subtraction works but multiplication does not work.
I convert operand into a char character, and use a switch statement to direct the operation.
When using multiplication.

```
./calc 4 * 3
output: 
Usage: ./calc x operand y
x: First number
operand: Integer operation
y: Second number
```

Here is my code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int x, y;
  char operand;
  if (argc != 4) {
    printf("Usage: %s x operand y\n", argv[0]);
    printf("x: First number\n");
    printf("operand: Integer operation\n");
    printf("y: Second number\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  x = atoi(argv[1]);
  y = atoi(argv[3]);
  operand = argv[2][0];
  switch(operand) {
  case '+':
    printf("%d\n", x + y);
    break;
  case '-':
    printf("%d\n", x - y);
    break;
  case '/':
    printf("%d\n", x / y);
    break;
  case '*':
    printf("%d\n", x * y);
    break;
  default:
    printf("Operand does not exist\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Running a *nix operating system?  What could possibly go wrong when you use `*`...

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Your program works correctly. It accepts 3 arguments. You cannot possibly mind all the quirks other programs which launch your program might have. The user is responsible for launching your program correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost certainly because the *shell* is interpreting `*` as "give me a list of all files in the current directory".

Try:

```
./calc 4 '*' 3
```

instead, to stop this from happening.

Other possibilities are to, depending on your shell:

- use `x` for multiplication, instead of `*`.
- use `\*` as another way to prevent expansion.
- use `set -f` to turn off wildcard expansion.
- use `setopt noglob` to turn off wildcard expansion.

There's nothing you can do in your C program to prevent expansion since the expansion is done well before the C program starts running, and I'm unaware of any C implementations capable of temporal transformations.

Comment: Oh I see, Thank you. But the exercise clearly state the structure to be a * without the quotation mark. Is there any other way I can keep this structure?

Comment: Then use `\*` instead, or `set -f`, or `setopt noglob`, or run it in a directory with no files :-) Or realise that a C program has absolutely no power to change the behaviour of the shell that invokes it.

Comment: cs500 level answer - write your own shell without globbing

Comment: @Sarc: If you type `'*'`, `"*"`, or `\*` on the command line, the argument passed to the program will be `*` and nothing else. (An ugly hack would be to execute the command from a directory that contains just one file named `*`; did I mention that's an ugly hack?)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting bitten by "glob expansion" , see here :[(h)](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=glob%20expansion%20*) https://duckduckgo.com/?q=glob%20expansion%20*

If you're on bash, try ...

"set -f " typed at the command line

to turn **off** global expansion.

This will not "expand" the asteriksk ( '*' ) to **all files** .

You can turn glob-ing back **on** while by typing "set +f" in the command line.

Comment: I don't think I'd suggest turning off globbing. It's too easy to leave it off accidentally, which could cause a lot of confusion later on. Quoting the argument is easier.